# How to extract coefficients of a generating function like this one, using a computer?

Tags: combinatorics

For example if we have the generating function $G (x) = (1 + x + ... + x^k)^{10}$ and we want to calculate the coefficient of $x^{3k}$ as a function of $k $:
What is the best way to go about it using Mathematica?

Comment: `Assuming[k \[Element] Integers && k > 1, SeriesCoefficient[(-1 + x^(1 + k))^10/(-1 + x)^10, {x, 0, 3 k}] // FullSimplify]`.

Answer (score 7):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The closed-form of the [`Sum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html) is

```
G[x_, k_] = Sum[x^n, {n, 0, k}]^10

(* (-1 + x^(1 + k))^10/(-1 + x)^10 *)
```

The coefficient for the `x^(3k)` term of `G[x, k]` is

```
coef3k[k_] = 
 FindSequenceFunction[
   Table[SeriesCoefficient[G[x, k], {x, 0, 3 k}], {k, 1, 15}], k] // 
  FullSimplify

(* (1/90720)(1 + k) (2 + k) (3 + k) (15120 + 
   k (57552 + k (121438 + k (137565 + k (89110 + k (29163 + 3652 k)))))) *)
```

Verifying the result for `k` in the interval `{0, 200}`

```
And @@ Table[
  coef3k[k] == SeriesCoefficient[G[x, k], {x, 0, 3 k}],
  {k, 0, 200}]

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Define the function

```
a[n_, k_] := SeriesCoefficient[ Sum[x^i, {i, 0, k}]^10, {x, 0, n}];
```

and you want `a[3 k, k]`. By the way, this is a $9$th degree polynomial function as given by

```
FindSequenceFunction[Table[a[3 k, k], {k, 9+2}]]
```

where `FindSequenceFunction[]` is a bit finicky for polynomials of degree less than 2, but for quadratic and higher degree polynomials you need at least 2 more terms of the sequence than its degree.